# Is there a diminutive form of adjective in English language?

Tags: adjectives, word-form

My native language is Russian, and it has very many diminutive forms. For example: the Russian word "малый" means "small" or "little", and this word has a diminutive form "маленький"... but I have not found much information about diminutives in English.
I heard something about the "-y" suffix, so is "littly" or "smally" a correct form?

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Nyan Cat! You might want to ask this question at the [Linguistics Stack Exchange](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/), or at [English Language and Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions), I guess they would love to answer. There is indeed the **-y/ly** form in English, and there is the rarely used suffix **[-kin](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_words_suffixed_with_-kin)** found in several words (pannikin, ladykin, catkin, nipperkin..).

Comment: Here's [a search for "diminutive"](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=diminutive) at ELU, here's [a search for "diminutive"](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/search?q=diminutive) at Linguistics SE - you might want to look if there are possibly answers to your question among the finds.

Comment: **-ish** is not a diminutive. I state that strongly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A progression of adjectives related to size would be: *small, tiny, teensy* — "teensy" being even smaller than "tiny". Note that *teensy* would never be used in formal writing. Another example is *cutesy*.  However, this morphological change is not a generalizable production.

Answer (score 3):

In English we have the suffix *"-ish",* which can be aplied to many, but not all adjectives. It means "like that, but not so much",  so in a way it is diminutive.  for example:

*smallish, greenish, mannish, etc.*

It would generally be understood this way if you coined an uncommon word with {adjective}+ -ish (say it with a distinct pause at the hyphen, so they can tell you know it's not a standardized word); For example:

*funny-ish, clumsy-ish, huge-ish, cold-ish, round-ish, square-ish, young-ish*

(there's a comedy on American TV called Black-ish)

but *-ish* can also mean "like that" (and **not** just a little bit) when attached to a few nouns: *oafish, childish, churlish, foolish, foppish, rakish.*

Or "a person or dialect from there":
*British, Swedish, Polish, Spanish*

Comment: **-ish** does not signify either *1. much smaller than the average or usual; tiny.* or 
*2. pertaining to or productive of a form denoting smallness, familiarity, affection, or triviality, as the suffix -let in droplet from*

Comment: Did I say that it did?

Answer (score 0):

I would say if you want to express a lesser degree of an adjective you say: a bit expensive, not very useful, little helpful, rather small. You don't do it by adding   suffixes.